# How to Connect Visual Basic 2008 to mySQL

Tags: mysql, vb.net, wamp

..Guys is this even possible, to connect VB2008 with MySQL inside WAMP Server?
.i have already downloaded the MySQL Connector/ODBC from mysql.com but whenever i try to connect using a query it returns an error saying "Connection mus be valid and is open".

.can anyone please guide me on how to do this thing right? Help pls! Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Accessing MySQL Database from my VB.NET 2008 Project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2279138/accessing-mysql-database-from-my-vb-net-2008-project)

Comment: also (better) [Can Visual Studio Express 2008 connect to MySQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5601075/can-visual-studio-express-2008-connect-to-mysql)

Comment: .the page that you have given is pertaining to VB.NET connection to MySQL.. What I am trying to do is connect Visual Basic 2008 to MySQL server. Visual Basic Windows Form Project.

Comment: @zerey ah, fair enough. My ignorance, sorry. However note that there is no "mySQL server", just "mySQL"

Comment: .by using MySQL server in my reply to your comment i didn't mean it as "MySQL Server" but "MySQL" as a server.. anyway thanks for your opinion.

Comment: I believe the MySQL Connector need to open connections before using it, unlike the SqlClient Classes. Would you show us some (simplified) code how you use the Connector?

Comment: @zerey yeah, no problem. (Bringing it up just to avoid confusion, not to nitpick)